# Sort by author in Alpha bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, sorting

Using the `alpha` bibliography style, citations are sorted by the citation key. I'd like to use the same style of authors-year citation keys (e.g., [CP92]) but have the bibliography sorted by the first author's lastname instead of alphabetically by the citation key itself. This would keep the same papers by the same first author together.

For example, `alpha` would produce the following sorted order:

> - [Cha81] D. Chaum. Untraceable...
> - [CL04] J. Camenisch and A. Lysyanskaya. Signature...
> - [CP92] D. Chaum and T. Pedersen. Wallet...

Whereas, `abbr` would produce the following sorted order:

> - [1] J. Camenisch and A. Lysyanskaya. Signature...
> - [2] D. Chaum. Untraceable...
> - [3] D. Chaum and T. Pedersen. Wallet...

I am looking for the same sorting as `abbr` but maintaining the citation key style of `alpha`.

Is there a way to achieve this hybrid style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For users of traditional BibTeX, i.e., without using `biblatex`:
Copy `TEXMF/bibtex/bst/base/alpha.bst` to a new file `alpha-abbrvsort.bst` in a place where BibTeX will find it. Open it in an text editor, locate the function `presort`, and comment the four lines as shown here:

```
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  % sort.label   %% four lines commented out to obtain presort of abbrv.bst
  % "    "       %%
  % *            %%
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.organization.sort
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.organization.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  % *            %%
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

Save and close, and use it as normal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{PulpSpy.bib}
  @misc{a, author={Chaum, D.}, title = {Untracable ...}, year = {1981}}
  @misc{b, author={Chamenisch, J. and Lysyanskaya, A.}, title={Signature...}, year={2004}}
  @misc{c, author={Chaum, D. and T. Pedersen, T.}, title={Wallet...}, year={1992}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha-abbrvsort}
\bibliography{PulpSpy}
\end{document}
```

Works:

[image: reference output]

Answer (score 9):

If you're willing to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html), here's how to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{C,
  author = {Chaum, D.},
  year = {1981},
  title = {Untraceable \dots},
}    
@misc{CL,
  author = {Camenisch, J. and Lysyanskaya, A.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Signature \dots},
}
@misc{CP,
  author = {Chaum, D. and Pedersen, T.},
  year = {1992},
  title = {Wallet \dots},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it will work. I didn't verify it (since lofreq.def, a dependency of biblatex, is producing a weird error for me).

Comment: @Jeremy: logreq is a small separate package which is included in the current versions of TeXLive and MiKTeX.

Comment: Thanks, I think upgrading MacTeX (in my case) will solve the problem (the logreq error is related to etoolbox being outdated, according others online who had the same error). At 1.5GB, it is a bit of a commitment though.

Comment: I finally tried this out and it works great: Thanks! I am using \usepackage[style=alphabetic,terseinits=true,firstinits=true,sorting=nyt,backref=true,maxnames=4,minnames=3]{biblatex} and \printbibliography[maxnames=10] (via your tip in my other question). It models what I want quite closely.