# bibtex incorrectly sorting authors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Using `pdflatex` pi-2.6-1.40.15 and `BibTeX` 0.99d, when compiling my LaTeX documents with multiple .bib files, some of my references are not sorted by the first author last name properly.  As an example, `book.bib` I have

```
@book {Connes,
    AUTHOR = {Connes, Alain},
     TITLE = {Noncommutative geometry},
 PUBLISHER = {Academic Press, Inc.},
   ADDRESS = {San Diego, CA},
      YEAR = {1994},
}

@book {Conway, 
    AUTHOR = {Conway, John B.},
     TITLE = {A Course in Functional Analysis},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1990},
    SERIES = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {96},
   EDITION = {2nd ed},
}
```

and in `article.bib`,

```
@article {Connes1989,
    AUTHOR = {Connes, Alain},
     TITLE = {Compact metric spaces, {F}redholm modules, and hyperfiniteness},
   JOURNAL = {Ergodic Theory Dynam. Systems},
  FJOURNAL = {Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems},
    VOLUME = {9},
      YEAR = {1989},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {207--220},
}
```

bibtex will sort in the bibliography of document: Connes1989 first, then Conway, and finally Connes.

A test document for which I can see this behavior is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Connes}
\cite{Connes1989}
\cite{Conway}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{./book,./article}

\end{document}
```

This is confusing because some authors are properly sorted and others are not.

Comment: Without a minimal document that shows which bibliography style you are using this will not be possible to answer.

Comment: Sorting is determined by the bibliography style that's in use. Which one do you use?

Comment: Please also show in the minimal document, how you include te multiple bib files.

Comment: Added a minimal document now and the example bib files.

Comment: I don't know much about the `alpha` style, but I suspect this behaviour is by design: it's sorting on the labels `[ConYY]` and so `[Con94]` comes after `[Con90]` in the sort order.

Comment: Using the `plain` style, these are sorted properly.  This, I guess, changes the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour with the `alpha` bibliography style.  From the `bibtex` documentation (p.5):

> The alpha style, however, sorts first by label, then “author”, year, and title.

This means that [Con89], [Con90] and [Con94] is the correct order according to that style.

If you want to continue to use the `alpha` style, then you can make a copy of `alpha.bst` and modify it to sort only by author and not label. Here's a question that does exactly that:

- [Sort by author in Alpha bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13944/2693)